# Select unique attributes group

Tags: xml, xslt

I have very poor xslt background and I need to transform XML that looks like this:

```
<row attribute1="1" attribute2="something" attribute3="somevalue">
<row attribute1="1" attribute2="something" attribute3="somevalue">
<row attribute1="2" attribute2="anotherthing" attribute3="somevalue">
```

In something that looks like this:

```
<row attribute1="1">
<row attribute1="2">
```

The transformation task has two more requirements. I'd like to get the same result as above but I'd like to change attribute name, for example:

```
<row new_name_for_attribute1="1">
<row new_name_for_attribute1="2">
```

The last requirement is that the method can be applied to single attributes (like previous examples), a subset of them (attribute1 and attribute3), or all attributes of the row element

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily transform the XML. Here's a little code that you can study and learn some xsl.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
       <xsl:copy>
           <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
       </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <!-- drop a row that matches a previous row of the same id -->
   <xsl:template match="row[ preceding-sibling::row/@attribute1 = @attribute1 ]" />

   <!-- do stuff with the row. this template is equivalent to the default template copy. -->
   <xsl:template match="row">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <!-- drop attribute2 attributes -->
   <xsl:template match="@attribute2" />

   <!-- rename attribute1 -->
   <xsl:template match="@attribute1">
      <xsl:attribute name="new_name_for_attribute1">
         <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </xsl:attribute>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Using this input:

```
<table>
   <row attribute1="1" attribute2="something" attribute3="somevalue">
      <p>foo</p>
   </row>
   <row attribute1="1" attribute2="something" attribute3="somevalue">
      <p>bar</p>
   </row>
   <row attribute1="2" attribute2="anotherthing" attribute3="somevalue">
      <p>bazinga</p>
   </row>
</table>
```

Gets you this output:

```
<table>
   <row new_name_for_attribute1="1" attribute3="somevalue">
      <p>foo</p>
   </row>
   <row new_name_for_attribute1="2" attribute3="somevalue">
      <p>bazinga</p>
   </row>
</table>
```

Comment: Many thanks, It worked. If I wanted to filter by more than one attribute I should just add them to the 'preceding-siblings' expression?

Comment: Right. If you wanted to filter by distinct attribute1 and attribute3 pairs, it would be 
row[ preceding-sibling::row/\@attribute1 = \@attribute1 and 
     preceding-sibling::row/\@attribute3 = \@attribute3 ]

Comment: (ignore the backslash... SO complained that I was trying to notify too many users)

Comment: Is it somehow possible to change the <table> and <row> tag text? Something like <Table> to <NewTable>

Comment: I'll try to answer, but if I'm misunderstanding you'll have to start a new question... You just need to match on 'table'; and instead of using xsl:copy just output 'Table' element. 

<xsl:template match="table"><Table>...</Table></xsl:template>

Answer (score 2):

If you are keen to learn more about the intricacies of XSLT, you might be interested to know of a technique called [Muenchian Grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html) which could be used to solve your problem. To get your distinct rows you effectively group them by **attribute1** and then select the first element in the group for each group. (Or discard the elements that are not first). Muenchian Grouping is the most efficient way to achieve this in XSLT 1.0.

In this case, you start off by defining a key to indicate your group, which in your case is **row** elements, grouped by **attribute1**

```
<xsl:key name="row" match="row" use="@attribute1" />
```

If you then wanted to select the distinct **row** elements, you would select the **row** elements which occurred first in the key for their given **attribute1**

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="row[generate-id() = generate-id(key('row', @attribute1)[1])]" />
```

Alternatively, you could have a template to ignore **row** elements that were duplicates (i.e which were not first in the group)

```
<xsl:template match="row[generate-id() != generate-id(key('row', @attribute1)[1])]" />
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
   <xsl:key name="row" match="row" use="@attribute1" />

   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="row[generate-id() != generate-id(key('row', @attribute1)[1])]" />   
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to the following XML

```
<rows>
   <row attribute1="1" attribute2="something" attribute3="somevalue" />
   <row attribute1="1" attribute2="something" attribute3="somevalue" />
   <row attribute1="2" attribute2="anotherthing" attribute3="somevalue" />
</rows>
```

The following is output

```
<rows>
   <row attribute1="1" attribute2="something" attribute3="somevalue"></row>
   <row attribute1="2" attribute2="anotherthing" attribute3="somevalue"></row>
</rows>
```

The XSLT could easily be extended to rename attributes, or exclude them, as described in ljdelight's answer. Furthermore, if you wanted to include a second attribute in your test, you could extend your key like so:

```
<xsl:key name="row" match="row" use="concat(@attribute1, '|', @attribute3)" />
```

And to ignore the duplicates, the template would look this this

```
<xsl:template match="row
     [generate-id() != generate-id(key('row', concat(@attribute1, '|', @attribute3))[1])]" />
```

The only thing to note here is the use of the pipe character | as a delimiter. This could be any other character if required, just as long as it doesn't occur in the attribute value.

Comment: Great idea! +1 I had never thought of using a concat along with Muenchian grouping

Comment: Tanks for this suggestion. I will also try this one when I get back to my xslt activity :-)